# Would having no power supply but a large input signal damage the amplifier?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, power-sequencing

I am now learning about the power sequence of the circuit. And wonder that as every amplifier has its own limited input voltage (for example: ADA4004's input limit is V− < VIN < V+), would the amplifier be damaged if no power supply but a large signal (maybe +-2V) injected into the input pin of the amplifier?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is bad practice to apply input signals to a device before applying power. When you do this, you can cause semiconductors to 'latch up'. The semiconductor can act due to its physical build as a [SCR (Silicon Controlled Rectifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon-controlled_rectifier), which can cause it to short out its pins. Subsequential application of power can cause excessive currents which destroy the device.

This does not only apply for single chips, but also for modules. Recently chips have been designed with internal protection diodes, but I doubt you want to rely on them for this. Modules that are hot swapable can most of the time be recognized by the fact that the power supply pins are slightly longer than signal pins, enforcing power to be applied before any signal.

Comment: Yeah. I just read some articles about the power sequence.They told me to use power sequencer for the ADC/DAC or DSP. However, little mention about the opamp.So do you think it is very necessary to use sequencer for ADC/DAC as well as the opamp?

Comment: @billyzhao all integrated circuits potentially suffer from this issue.

Comment: Actually most datasheets will specify the absolute maximum ratings, one of which will be input voltage with respect to power supply rails @billyzhao

Answer (score 1):

With no power supply, the transistors in the IC would not do anything, so the input would be "ignored"...and there would be no output. It requires a power supply to open the switches to let the signal in.

Comment: But some amplifiers will allow unlimited current flow from inputs to supply rails whenever an input exceeds rails by some margin (which is to be found in the datasheet). If the input source impedance is low enough, and the power up sequence is slow, I believe this could well lead to amp destruction.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the amplifier or other device... SOME devices can be destroyed by applying any significant input voltage without first appying power. OTHER devices are totally immune.

I'm not sure whether this qualifies as an "answer", because it doesn't specifically address the ADA4004; I haven't seen that device's specs.