# Can this low-pass filter for audio possibly work without a power source?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

In [MOSQUITO: Covert Ultrasonic Transmissions between Two Air-Gapped Computers using Speaker-to-Speaker Communication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03422.pdf), M. Guri et al describe a malware capable of bridging air gaps and creating a bi-directional covert channel by turning connected audio output devices, e.g., speakers, headphones, etc., into microphones using what's called jack restasking.

One of the countermeasures proposed is using a low-pass filter circuit like the one shown here: [image: here] No specific components or parts are mentioned or suggested.

Would it be possible to make this circuit work without connecting a power source to it?

One of the answers to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125701/would-having-no-power-supply-but-a-large-input-signal-damage-the-amplifier) mentions:

`In general it is bad practice to apply input signals to a device before applying power. When you do this, you can cause semiconductors to 'latch up'. The semiconductor can act due to its physical build as a SCR (Silicon Controlled Rectifier), which can cause it to short out its pins.`

and another says:
`With no power supply, the transistors in the IC would not do anything, so the input would be "ignored"...and there would be no output. It requires a power supply to open the switches to let the signal in.`

Right now, I'm looking at using either an LM358 or LM386 for the amplifier as they are what I have available, but would there any amplifiers out there that could make this work without an external power supply attached?

Comment: You would have to apply power to the op amp for this filter. You *could* use a passive low-pass filter, presumably.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I will definitely look into that. Thanks for suggesting it. The two answers to that question I mentioned present different outcomes. If I built this circuit with either of the amplifiers I mentioned and applied no power, which of these would happen?

Comment: I couldn't tell you, as it depends on the exact IC you use (may differ even between manufacturers of the same model number, or even between batches), the amplitude of the signals fed into it, the temperature of the circuit, and who knows what else. It would be using the op amp outside of its specified conditions, so you won't be able to get any sort of guarantee as to what happens. In general, treat anything operating outside its specified conditions as though it'll immediately release the magic smoke, because you can't be sure it will work afterward.

Comment: There's no such thing as an amplifier that doesn't use a power supply. This circuit will not work for you. You need a different circuit.

Comment: Some circuits may marginally work by leeching power from the signal via the ESD protection diodes. You should never design a circuit to do this. It can be an unintended consequence that has caused me great heartache over the years.

Comment: @Mattman944 The only place I've ever seen this happen is with some MCUs and some OLD digital gates.  The signal we are talking about here is audio so there won't be much there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no circuit that had an active amplifier works without a power supply.